# How to copy files by applying transformations to content in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, copy, buffer

I have a template file that I want to change when copying it. So, my template file would look like this:

**template.js**

```
$name
```

When I copy this file, I would like to change the $name content to something like User, Company, etc...

**User.js**

```
user
```

**Company.js**

```
company
```

I am using [NCP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) to perform the copy, and it has the "transform" option (which gives me access to the read and write streams) but I do not know how to manipulate them to perform this transformation.

```
ncp('../patterns/template.js', /*THIS IS MY TEMPLATE FILE */
    './app/routes/user.js', /*THIS IS THE DESTINATION FILE */
    {
       /* HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO PERFORM THE TRANSFORMATION */
       transform: function(read, write){ read.pipe(write); } /
    }, (err) => {
          if(err) console.log(err);
    }
);
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure you can modify the file through the stream because it means working with chunk of the file only, not the file as a whole. In your use case it seems you want to apply logic on your file content. I'd say you need to read the file, transform it once you got it all in memory then save it. (`fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile`)

Comment: @Thom I believe you are correct. I changed the strategy and now I'm using handlebars to compile the template file.